# How can I generate unique tag names in yml, for GitHub Action releases?

Tags: yaml, tags, github-actions

My group and I are having issues with auto releases in Github Actions.

Our releases are scheduled twice a week. However, they fail because the tag_name in the yml files are not unique. Is there some way to generate unique names for the attribute tag_name? Such as commit sha, timestamps etc...

Below is the code:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    

name: Create Release

jobs:
  build:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
          body: |
            Release on push
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

Thanks in advance hope my question makes sense :)

So far I have tried several ways of using timestamps and commit sha... Non of it worked out.

Comment: Couple comments on this: (1) the action you're using is unmaintained so you should probably look for an alternative, (2) what do you mean with "twice per week"? This workflow is run whenever you push, (3) can you show the error message? since the action runs on push and you use the `ref` as a tag, this should be unique?